# Dealing with shared credentials when an employee leaves

Tags: account-security, credentials, user-management

We have around 20+ accounts of different services (company email inboxes, forums, social media, Github, etc.) we use in my team. For security reasons, whenever some employee leaves us, I need to change the password for all those services. Luckily, it's happened twice in a three years span, but it's still a pain.

How do you deal with shared credentials when an employee leaves? Especially if you're in a large organization where people are coming and leaving on a monthly basis. Many of those services don't provide LDAP integration, so even if we disable their account, they still have access to the service.

Comment: More than a pain, it exposes a real security weakness if not done properly, consistently, and audited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **re-engineer your account management** process, where possible, so that users have personal admin accounts and the built-in admin account is disabled, or that built-in account password is stored in a secure location such that your admins cannot get unauthorised access to it (e.g. password vault).

Second, if you cannot use account separation on the device/service level, then consider using one of the many **privileged access tools** or **Cloud Service Brokers (CSB)** (e.g. CyberArc, Thycotic, etc.) so that only the system knows the password and account separation is achieved on a management layer. Blocking access to a user is a 1-click operation in the tool. Changing passwords is equally easy and the authorised users experience no change or inconvenience.

Third, even if you do the above, you have a **manual documentation and audit process** to engage:

1. document all services that need to be managed
2. document all accounts and users on each service
3. review all accounts/users on a periodic basis (annually? quarterly? monthly?) to confirm fitness
4. audit the completeness of all services and accounts

Obviously, a privileged access tool or a Cloud Service Broker is the way to go for consistency and uptime.